# Android TV Emulator KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER event not dispatched

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When using the Android TV (1080p) 29API virtual device I've found that the `KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` `KeyEvent` is never fired. It also doesn't cause a button click event to fire either.

```
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event != null) {
            when (event.keyCode) {
                // This first match is never hit
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER -> Log.d("DPAD", "Center")
                // The rest of these all work fine
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP -> Log.d("DPAD", "UP")
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN -> Log.d("DPAD", "DOWN")
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT -> Log.d("DPAD", "RIGHT")
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT -> Log.d("DPAD", "LEFT")
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I solved this was by using a physical Android TV device for debugging. Hopefully this will save some of you the amount of time I wasted dealing with the emulator before I decided to just use a real TV.

Comment: can you share your result?

Comment: @AliYusuf I had to use a physical tv, the emulator doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It's working only on the emulator, but for fast testing, you can map any unused button to dispatch the CENTER evetfor example I used `KEYCODE_BOOKMARK` button to dispatch it in the debug mode only

```java
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BOOKMARK) {
    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER));
    return true;
}
```